# Bernoulli random variable question

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $E[X] = 3\text{Var}(X)$. Find $P(X=0)$ and also $E[3X]$.

I know that $E[X] = np$ and $\text{Var}(X)= np(1-p)$ but i do not know to how use what I already know to solve this problem. This  $E[X] = 3\text{Var}(X)$ throws me off completely.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused this with a Binomial Random Variable. A [Bernoulli R.V.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) has only one trial. There is no $n$. $E(x) = p$ and $V(X) = p(1- p)$

Using your information we have $E(X) = 3V(x) \implies p = 3p(1 - p) \implies 1- p = \frac 1 3 \implies p = \frac 2 3$

The value of $P(X = 0)$ depends on how it is defined. If $0$ stands for failure then your answer is nothing but $ \frac 1 3 $.

$E(3x) = 3 E(X) = 3p = 2$

Comment: It doesnt tell me if 0 is for failure. However, for E[3x] i would do the same thing but instead it it being p it would be 3p?

Comment: That should not matter. I would go with $\frac 1 3$. If the question does not specify either answer - $\frac 1 3$ or $\frac 2 3$  - should  be considered correct. And $E(aX) = aE(X)$ is a relationship you should be taught without which I can safely say you cannot solve the problem. Read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Answer (score 0):

$np=3np(1-p)$

$n \ne 0$

$p=3p(1-p)$

$p \ne 0$

$1=3(1-p)$

$1-p=\frac{1}{3}$

$p=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$

$P(X=0)=(2/3)^n$

$E(3X)=3E(X)=3n(2/3)=2n$